# How do I run indent intelligently on bufferRead with vim

Tags: c, vim

I'd like to run indent on each .c and .h file I open in vim. I've looked at setting equalprg, but I'd rather have it done for me when I open the buffer, so I tried:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.[ch] '[,']!indent
```

This works fine if the file has no syntax errors, but spews error messages from indent into the file if I'm missing a closing brace, say. I haven't done anything with plugins before. Am I better off writing an ftplugin?  I don't mind silent failure on errors, but the file should be left pristine in that case.  Any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use GNU indent.  It sounds like you want something like:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.[ch] silent !indent "%"
set autoread
```

(Also untested) :-)

Comment: This results in an oddity: The file is formatted, but the vim buffer is empty. I get the message:
W11: Warning: File "web_server.c" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File: 

I choose "L" and get a blank buffer. :-(

Setting autoread just automates that process. :-(

Comment: But this works:

autocmd BufReadPost *.[ch] silent !indent "%" 
set autoread

Comment: The comment didn't let me format it, but "set autoread" should be on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

How about (untested):

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.[ch] gg=G
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to run GNU indent, not the built in indent.  I have lots of preferences configured that vim's indent doesn't handle.